# Spark Countbykey() - why implemented as an action

Tags: apache-spark, action, transformation

In Spark why CountbyKey() is implemented as an action rather than a transformation. I think functionality wise it is similar to Reducebykey or combinebykey. Is there any specific reason why this is implemented as Action..

Comment: Literally about to ask this question and your question came up as a similar question.  Seems no one knows the answer? :D

Answer (score 0):

It counts the value of RDD consisting of two components tuple for each distinct key. It actually counts the number of elements for each key and return the result to the master as lists of (key, count) pairs.

Example:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Spark",78),("Hive",95),("spark",15),("HBase",25),("spark",39),("BigData",78),("spark",49)))
rdd1.countByKey
```

Output:

```
scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(Hive -> 1, BigData -> 1, HBase -> 1, spark -> 3, Spark -> 1)
```